# is there any similar function in python poloars like 'transform' in pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

in pandas , i can run the code like:

```
day = ['day1','day2','day3','day4','day1','day2','day3','day1','day2']

code = ["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"]

price = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":day,"code":code,"price":price})


df['codeindex'] = df.groupby('code')['date'].transform(lambda x: range(0, len(x), 1))
```

in pandas i can generate such a column 'codeindex' using transform.  how can i do that in py-polars?

thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window expressions` to deal with expressions that only need to be applied within a group.

A windows expression operates on groups you partition by with `.over()`. It is defined by an expression part like `col("date").cumcount()` and a partition part defined by `.over("code")`.

If you use an `aggregation` the result will be broadcasted to match the size of the group.

The code looks like this:

```py
day = ['day1','day2','day3','day4','day1','day2','day3','day1','day2']

code = ["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"]

price = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

df = pl.DataFrame({"date":day,"code":code,"price":price})

(df.select([
    pl.all(),
    pl.col("date").cumcount().over("code").alias("codeindex"),
]))
```

### outputs

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ date ┆ code ┆ price ┆ codeindex │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64   ┆ u32       │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ day1 ┆ a    ┆ 1     ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day2 ┆ a    ┆ 2     ┆ 1         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day3 ┆ a    ┆ 3     ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day4 ┆ a    ┆ 4     ┆ 3         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day2 ┆ b    ┆ 6     ┆ 1         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day3 ┆ b    ┆ 7     ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day1 ┆ c    ┆ 8     ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ day2 ┆ c    ┆ 9     ┆ 1         │
└──────┴──────┴───────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: thx a lot dude!

Comment: hi dude, i reinstall my windows10 and anaconda today. and find the polars code cannot work for the Flatten in window functions..RuntimeError: Any(ComputeError("This operation is likely not what you want. Please open an issue if you really want to do this"))

Comment: tried  2 computers already ..all cannot work which drive me crazy :(

Comment: I shall update my answer the rules for window functions have changed.

Comment: that is great! looking forwards to the update